# Show value in textarea if checkbox is true

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with four columns Name, Age, Country and a checkbox. If the checkbox is clicked(true) the `name` value of the row is showed in a `textarea`.

I am not really sure how I can realise that.

A row:

```html
<tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>James</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
```

if the checkbox is true the value "James" should be shown in a textarea.

Thank you all.

Comment: What should the textarea have when you have checkboxes set in multiple rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I believe you need to do this for multiple rows in a table.*

First select all the *checkboxes* with [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to attach the event (*click*) to all the *checkboxes*.

> The Document method [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

Inside the event (*click*) handler function target all the checked *checkboxes* to loop through them to get the *relevant names* using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Also it is not good practice to mix up *th* and *td* inside of the same *tr* element. You should place *th* inside of a *thead* and *td* inside of *tbody* element:

```js
var cb = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
cb.forEach(function(ck){
  ck.addEventListener('click', function(el){
    var checked = document.querySelectorAll(':checked');
    var tArea = document.getElementById('myText');
    tArea.value = Array.from(checked).map(c => c.closest('tr').querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').textContent);
    //or using spread syntax
    //tArea.value = [...checked].map(c => c.closest('tr').querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').textContent);
  });
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sl</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">1</td>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>France</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">2</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>
```

Comment: great @Mamun thank you ! Just for understanding. What means "[...checked]" and "td:nth-child(2)"

Comment: @Lia, that is called spread syntax which allows to implement the `map()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax. You can also use `Array.from()`:)

Comment: td:nth-child(2) means 2nd td element in tr. [...checked] means you converted DOMCollection in array

Comment: @RiteshKhandekar, yes I did that and mentioned the reason behind that in the answer:)

Comment: @Mamun just for interest. How can I take the whole line? like this `querySelectorAll(' ')`?

Comment: @Lia, *`querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors*, updated the answer please check:)

Comment: @Mamun for just getting the name it is working perfect. But how can I change the code, that I get the whole first line when I click at the checkbox :D

Comment: ok I think I got it just do it like this: `(c => c.closest('tr').querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').textContent + c.closest('tr').querySelector('td:nth-child(3)').textContent);` maybe it is not the perfect solution :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")].forEach(function (v){
v.addEventListener("change", function(){
document.querySelector("textarea").value = (this).checked ? (this).parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("td").innerHTML:'';
})});
```

```html
<table>
             <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>James</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>France</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr> 
             <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>James</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>France</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr> 
</table>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Why do you want to load an external library to achieve something that can be done with JavaScript only?

Comment: @RiteshKhandekar it is working perfect ! But how can I handle it , that it works for every row which is checked. It is just working for the first row.

Comment: Just use `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Changed it for every querySelector but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Few javascript lines would be ok for you need.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('change', e=> {
  if(e.target.checked == true){
    // retreive tags
    let name = document.querySelector('.name');
    let textarea = document.querySelector('.textarea');
    // insert data
    textarea.innerText += name.innerText
  }
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td class="name">James</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>   
</table>

<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your table can have multiple rows, where each can have the checkbox set or not, the textarea could get zero, one or more names.

So you would need to listen the `change` event, and then iterate the rows to collect the names, to finally set the value of the textarea:

```js
let textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
let table = document.querySelector("table");
table.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    let names = [];
    for (let row of table.rows) {
        if (row.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").checked) {
            names.push( row.children[1].textContent);
        }
    }
    textarea.value = names.join("\n");
});
```

```html
<table><tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>James</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>France</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr><tr>
    <th scope="row">2</th>
    <td>Lucy</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr></table>
<textarea></textarea>
```